# Seach bar in Laravel 5.2 to get comments from Reddit API

Tags: php, api, laravel, reddit

I want to build an application which monitors what is being said about companies on Reddit.

The application will allow you to enter a search phrase, like "Microsoft". It will then search through all the latest comments on Reddit which contain the phrase "Microsoft"

I have chosen to do this in Laravel 5.2 but my question is, how would one go about making this API Call, what is the theory involved.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Vinelab\Http\Client as HttpClient;
use App\Requests\SearchRequest;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class SearchResults extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('results.search-results');
    }

    public function store(Requests\SearchRequest $request)
    {

        $search_phrase = $request->input('search');

        $client = new HttpClient;

        $response = $client->get('https://www.reddit.com/search.json?q='. $search_phrase .'');

        $responseArray = $response->json();

        dd($responseArray);

        return view('results.search-results');

    }
}
```

The above code accesses a JSON array of data but only gives me threads and not comments, how would I be able to get the comments for a search phrase such as 'microsoft' and then parse them into an array that I can send to my view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just refer to the [Reddit documentation](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_search) for the research and to make the request you can use [Http](https://packagist.org/packages/vinelab/http) which is a simple http client.

The rest of the code is basic usage, just retrieve the result and do what you want on it

Comment: I have taken a look into this, thank you for the docs. My question is still, is it best practice to do this in the laravel controller? or is there another way

Comment: The best way in my opinion would be to do it in a Repository instead of directly in your controller (which is supposed to just retrieve information and retrieve method from Repository / something else)

Comment: So have them put in a command or model and then just call the api before returning the view?